# Creating shopping cart

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-passing

for my class were creating a mini store, and I have the three main functions that work, main.cpp, items.cpp, items.h. but the shoppingcart.cpp and the shoppinfcart.h keeps giving me issues, because I'm trying to pass the parameters from main.cpp, for example (sc1.add(&a) to the functions in shoppingcart.h and shopping cart.cpp.

I have attached copy of my code. any help will be appreciated.

**Item.h**

```
#ifndef Items_hpp
#define Items_hpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Items {
  private: 
  
  string ItemName;
  float ItemPrice;
  int ItemQuant;
  
  public:
  
  Items();
  
  Items(string in, float ip, int iq);
  
  void Name(string in);
  string entername();
  void CalcPrice( float ip);
  float enterprice();
  void CalcQuant(int iq);
  int enterquant();
  
};
#endif
```

**Items.cpp**

```
#include "Items.h"

Items::Items()
:ItemName("")
,ItemPrice(0)
,ItemQuant(0)
{
}


Items::Items(string in, float ip, int iq)
:ItemName(in)
,ItemPrice(ip)
,ItemQuant(iq)
{
}

void Items:: CalcPrice(float ip)
{
  ItemPrice = ip;
}

void Items::CalcQuant(int iq)
{
  ItemQuant = iq;
}

void Items:: Name(std::string in)
{
  ItemName = in;
}

float Items:: enterprice()
{
  return ItemPrice;
}

int Items:: enterquant()
{
  return ItemQuant;
}

string Items:: entername()
{
  return ItemName;
}
```

a snippet of the code for adding items to vector
**ShoppingCart.cpp**

```
#include "ShoppingCart.h" 
#include <vector>

void ShoppingCart ::add(&its)
{
shopitems.push_back(&its);
}
```

**ShoppingCart.h**

```
#ifndef ShoppingCart_hpp
#define ShoppingCart_hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Items.h"
using namespace std;


class ShoppingCart
{
  private:
  vector <const char its> shopitems;
  string cname; //customers name
  string cdate; // todays date

  public:
  ShoppingCart();
  ShoppingCart(string cname);
  void add( char *its);
};


#endif
```

an example of main
**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Items.h" 
#include "ShoppingCart.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char choice;
  int itemsbuy;
  float org = .75;
  float appl = .25;
  float pear = 1.00;
  float bana = .85;
  float grape = 6.00;
  float oatmlk = 5.00;
  float almmlk = 6.00;
  float cashmlk= 5.00;
  float soymlk = 4.00;
  float cocomlk = 3.00;
  float twopermlk = 3.00;
  float vitdmlk = 4.00;
  float fatmlk = 4.00;
  float goatmlk = 6.00;
  float rasinbran = 4.00;
  float granola = 5.00;
  float honeybunches = 6.00;
  float twix = 4.00;
  float honey = 5.00;
  float yogurt = 1.50;
  float cashyog = 2.00;
  float eggs = 1.80;
  float vegeggs = 3.00;
  float cheese = 2.00;
  float alcheese = 3.00;
  int itemop;
  int itemno;
  int productcounter = 0;
  int productsum= 0;//might need.
  
  

  cout << "Welcome to J&S Breakfast Grocery store!"<<endl;
  cout << "--------------------------------------"<<endl;
  cout << "How many items will you be purchasing today?"<<endl;
  cout << endl;
  cin >> itemsbuy;
  ShoppingCart sc1;                        //**intializing "shoppingcart.h"**//
  for (int i = 0; i < itemsbuy; i++) {
    cout << "Menu:"<<endl;
    cout << "---------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << "A. Fruits"<<endl;
    cout << "B. Non-Diary"<<endl;
    cout << "C. Diary" <<endl;
    cout << "D. Cereal" <<endl;
    cout << "E. Other"<<endl;
    cout << "Please select your type of items to add to cart"<<endl;
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;
    switch (choice) {
      case 'A':
      case 'a':
        cout << "Menu:" <<endl;
        cout << "---------------------------"<<endl;
        cout << "1.Oranges -$ "<< org<<endl;
        cout << "2.Apples -$ "<< appl << endl;
        cout << "3.Pears - $"<<pear<<endl;
        cout << "4.Bananas - $" << bana << endl;
        cout << "5.Grapes - $" << grape << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Chooose option"<<endl;
        cin >> itemop;
        cout << "How Many?"<<endl;
        cin >> itemno;
        if (itemno > itemsbuy) {
          cout << "Error, cannot add more than youre planning to buy. Please start over."<<endl;
          break;
        }
        else {
        if (itemop ==1) {
          Items a("Oranges" , org, itemno);
          productcounter++;
          sc1.add(&a);                       //**trying to pass parameter here**//
          if (productcounter == itemsbuy) {
           cout<< "Error. You are attempting to buy more than you planned. Please Start over. Thank you."<<endl;
          }
        }
```

Comment: `sc1.add(&a);`  the variable `a` is local to the scope defined by the closest {}. When it goes out of scope the pointer you store is no longer valid.

Comment: `vector <const char its> shopitems;` should be `vector <Items> shopitems;` and `void add( char *its);` should be `void add( Items it);` or maybe `void add( const Items & it);`

Comment: And `void add( char *its);` should be `void add(const Item& its)` and definition on Shopping.cpp should be: `void ShoppingCart::add(const Item& its)`

Comment: All of your `float` items should be marked as `static const`, so that the compiler can place the constants into the read-only section of your executable.

Comment: Also, look up `std::toupper` and `std::tolower`, so you can convert your input to all upper case or all lower case and use only `if` statement or one `case` statement.

Comment: thank you guys! Ive been up for two days since this is a quick summer class so my mind is a bit joggily. I appreciate you guys taking the time out of your day to help! Ill let you know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes in your code.

1. **ShoppingCart.h**:

`vector <const char its> shopitems;`.

`std::vector` is declared in the following syntax:
`std::vector<data type> variable name`.
It looks like that you're trying to create a container of `Items` and store them. Therefore instead of `vector<const char> shopitems`, you should use:
`vector<Items> shopitems` instead.

also:

`void add(char* its);` is incorrect, since this method will be adding `Items` to your `shopitems` vector. Change it to: `void add(const Items& its);`
This will pass a const reference of object `Items`, meaning the method will not copy the entire class `Items` when it is called, and the object will not be modifiable.

2. **ShoppingCart.cpp**:

Let's also fix the syntax and semantic in your .cpp file, the correct now is:

```
void ShoppingCart::add(const Item& its)
{
    shopitems.push_back(its); //& is not necessary here.
}
```

3. **Main.cpp**

Now, in your main file let's call the method correctly. `sc1.add(&a);`, the: **&** here is telling it to pass the memory address of where the object `Items a` is located. Let's correct this, and pass the object `Items a` normally, simply write: `sc1.add(a);`

4. **Logic error**

There is one final logic error I caught in your code, that is: `if (productcounter == itemsbuy)`. If `itemsbuy` (The amount of items you want to buy today) is: **1**. Then, `productcounter` is also **1** and you can't buy anything, this should be: `if (productcounter > itemsbuy)`

Comment: thank you! I will give this a try and tell you what goes down. thank you for taking the time out of your day to answer!